# A moderator is stalking me, downvoting and deleting my tried answer in seconds

Tags: support, disputed-flags

I read [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1403975/registry-add-string-value-to-regedit-via-reg-file/1403987).

I went to do research on it. tried myself, searched on net, made changes and eventually I could find the answer of this question. I even tried 2-3 variations to find what is correct and is working.

I went back and posted my answer.

Within seconds of my posting the answer, some has downvoted it (I guess DavidPostill himself, unless 2-3 moderators are stalking me), and has deleted the answer saying that it is a comment and not an answer.

[image]

This is my file showing its name, content, and confirmation message that it has been merged in registry.

[image]

And this is the [.reg file](https://jumpshare.com/v/NclJaLBA975vTTWRpeDl) that gave message of successful addition.

What more can I do to show that I had really done it.

And now, undeleting the question requires 3-4 votes that I don't have and these people are not going to vote in my favor, and my valid answer disappeared from the world.

So I want to to say that DavidPostill is stalking me at Superuser.com, downvoting me deleting my tried answer in seconds and thereby now he is harming the site's resources by deleting valid proven answer to reach the person asking question and others in future.

This week itself, 6 downvotes on my questions or answers were reversed by system on account of system finding them serial downvoting.

Feeling discouraged by such serial downvoting and other behavior I had myself deleted several of my questions and answers thus lost some other upvotes and helpful flags also.

I must have got 20-30 downvotes on my posts in all sites here. They chase me in other sites of the group and downvote my posts there also.

They have also snatched away my privilege to post question there, so I have to come post here.

They have also removed several replies on a discussion that I had started and moved that to chat, to hide it from people. This way they are distorting history to make believe that such thought was never expressed and such things were never discussed.

Please give it a thought and see whether such unruly behavior of this site's moderator harassing and bullying and discouraging new members is what you had in mind when you created this site to help people.

Comment: I suppose you are going to say that the downvote on this meta post is from DavidPostill as well.

Comment: @coldspeed Don't put words in my mouth, what I have said is said above. You sure seem to be siding with him, that you don't have any word to say on the above entire scenario and you are writing in favor of him.

Comment: Moderators usually have better things to do than 'stalk' random people around sites. Also, five minutes is quite a while in Internet time - not exactly "within seconds".

Comment: 1) "6 downvotes on my questions or answers were reversed by system"—never assume who votes on your posts. Voting is anonymous; anyone can vote on your posts if they have the privilege and I'd imagine mods would be the last to engage in serial voting. 2) "I had myself deleted several of my questions and answers thus lost some other upvotes" — Isn't this your fault? 3) "I must have got 20-30 downvotes on my posts in all sites here." — see 1) and really it's just your word here, so without actual evidence of abuse, it is difficult to say anything more.

Comment: 4) "They have also removed several replies on a discussion that I had started and moved that to chat, to hide it from people."— it is not "hidden", anyone can still see the chat by clicking the link. Your point is moot.

Comment: [My 2 year old answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1165070/how-to-copy-deleted-text-in-ms-word/1235609?noredirect=1#comment2117671_1235609) that DavidPostill Downvoted and deleted today at the same time he downvoted and deleted my above answer, 2 downvotes and 2 deletions within seconds, because he is using his moderator rights to dig up my activities and remove my contributions. [screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/dWEL4CZ.jpg)

Comment: @VSRawat - Your commentary which was flagged by members of the community was deleted, if that is even the case, if it was moved into a chat it was due to the fact you were having a discussion in the comments section.

Comment: I can't answer comments there because they say I make a lot of comments like chatting, then they move comments to chat as I mentioned above. So, this is my last comment here.

Comment: I'm not an expert but it looks like your answer is just a rehashing of theirs?

Comment: Additionally, [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1165070/how-to-copy-deleted-text-in-ms-word/1235609?noredirect=1#comment2117671_1235609) is considered to be commentary.  It was rightfully deleted due to the fact it was commentary submitted as an answer.  It should have never been submitted as an answer.  The question the answer belongs to had 4 low-quality answers deleted before yours.  It's not personal.  [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1403975/registry-add-string-value-to-regedit-via-reg-file/1403987) is commentary also.

Comment: @VSRawat: Comments being moved to chat is not a punishment. It's a valid response to a series of comments that are basically chat without being in chat. There's nothing wrong with comments being moved to chat.

Comment: @VSRawat "My 2 year old answer that DavidPostill Downvoted..." Why are you still insisting that you know exactly who downvoted what? Sure, you can see who cast a delete vote, but claiming that you know who downvoted sounds ridiculous because votes are fully anonymous. Just remove all your claims about knowing who voted and focus on the part of being close voted, otherwise you sound like you believe you can read minds or that you are omniscient or something, and no one will take you seriously.

Comment: 1. re: "new members", you don't have much rep, but you've been a site member for 6 1/2 yrs.  2. The site was created to help people, but only in a certain way.  It isn't a general purpose help site or forum.  It's a knowledge base for people to share good solutions to well-defined problems within a narrow range of topics, and it is curated by the users based on earned privileges.  The structure, rules, and moderation are to facilitate that objective.  (cont'd)

Comment: 3. It's not about you.  If it seems like your posts are receiving disproportionate negative attention, it's because a disproportionate share of them aren't consistent with site guidelines.  The system is working as designed and intended.  The solution is for you understand the site guidelines better.

Comment: Down votes are anonymous, so how do you know who did?

Comment: I know this is old, but I'm really confused as to why the answer in question was closed as being a comment. It may not be  a great answer, but it's indisputably an ANSWER and not just a comment. Call it a poorly worded answer maybe, but calling it commentary is absolutely, objectively wrong.

Comment: I feel pity with you. +1

Answer (score 17):

> I read [this question.](https://superuser.com/questions/1403975/registry-add-string-value-to-regedit-via-reg-file/1403987)
>
> I went to do research on it. tried myself, searched on net, made changes and eventually I could find the answer to this question. I even tried 2-3 variations to find what is correct and is working.
> [image]

What you submitted was considered commentary.  Commentary submitted as an answer will be flagged by the community and promptly deleted by the community through several votes or a binding moderator vote.

> Within seconds of my posting the answer, some has downvoted it (I guess DavidPostill himself unless 2-3 moderators are stalking me), and has deleted the answer saying that it is a comment and not an answer.

Your answers are appearing in a community review queue that is currently empty.  The queue being handled within minutes is not that odd.

> And now, undeleting the question requires 3-4 votes that I don't have and these people are not going to vote in my favor, and my valid answer disappeared from the world.

Your answer is not going to be undeleted by the community because it is commentary.

> Feeling discouraged by such serial downvoting and other behavior I had myself deleted several of my questions and answers thus lost some other upvotes and helpful flags also.

Removing contributions due to a couple downvotes which were reversed only will result in an answer ban.  Several of your answers are extremely low quality.  Hopefully, you only deleted answers which received downvotes or were consider commentary, instead of the contributions which received upvotes.  You shouldn't delete any contributions to be honest.

> They have also snatched away my privilege to post a question there, so I have to come to post here.

This is due to the low-quality questions you have asked in the past.  You were warned of the quality of your previous questions before this happened.  You will be allowed to ask another question at Super User in 6 months or when your contributions improve and receive enough upvotes.  ALL contributions count towards the automatic system that determines if you can or cannot submit new questions and/or answers.

> hey have also removed several replies on a discussion that I had started and moved that to chat, to hide it from people. This way they are distorting history to make believe that such thought was never expressed and such things were never discussed.

Your past commentary was either flagged by a community member and then deleted by a moderator or was converted into a chat.

As for your other answer that was also deleted, it was considered, the commentary also.

[image]

> Please give it a thought and see whether such unruly behavior of this site's moderator harassing and bullying and discouraging new members is what you had in mind when you created this site to help people.

The removal of commentary that is being flagged for moderator review is not considered moderator harassment.  It also is not considering bullying from the community.  Your contributions have issues, I know I have provided feedback on a few of them and saw no attempt to address those issues with the contributions I provided feedback on.

Comment: I was going to answer one of your questions, and instead of providing the clarification I asked for, you simply deleted the question because of a single downvote it received (I assume that is the reason).

Comment: It's also important to note that question and answer bans have almost nothing to do with users, moderators or really humans at all. Moderators can't assign or lift these bans: they're completely automated. The only way users are connected is by their collective downvotes eventually causing the ban.

Comment: @VSRawat, let me add one observation. You answer a lot of "bad" questions. These aren't really answerable by site definitions because they aren't clear, too broad in scope, off-topic, etc. It's great that you're trying to help the OP, but for those questions, it is very difficult to provide a good answer, especially one that will be seen as an answer rather than commentary. Answers get judged relative to expectations for good answers on good questions. Consider being more selective in what you answer.

Answer (score 6):

OK, I’m not familiar with your history of contributions,
so I can’t comment on that.

The tone of your (meta-) question (this one)
is inappropriately accusatory,
and I wonder whether you can produce any evidence
to support those accusations. 
(But it is suspiciously coincidental
that [an answer](https://superuser.com/q/1165070/150988#1235609) that got ***no votes*** or comments
for 1½ years then got downvoted and deleted on the same day.)

---

But — what am I missing? 
How is [the answer](https://superuser.com/q/1403975/150988#1403987) that is under discussion
(currently 10K-only, but visible above)
not an answer? 
How is it any worse than [the other answer](https://superuser.com/q/1403975/150988#1403982) to the same question? 
The only issues I see are

- VSRawat’s answer has some overlap with the other one, and
- VSRawat’s answer was posted 22 minutes later.

But VSRawat’s answer has some information that *isn’t* in the first answer. 
True, VSRawat’s answer doesn’t address the issue of specifying data in hex,
which [Gert Jan Kraaijeveld’s answer](https://superuser.com/q/1403975/150988#1403982) addresses — but so what? 
The question wasn’t about that.

What am I missing?